# SendGrid: Which API Key Sent the Email

Tags: sendgrid

Is there a way to determine which API Key sent a specific email and activity by API key? As I look at overall usage, I'm trying to gauge which module is sending the most emails, but I can't seem to find it in the UI or in the API docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, SendGrid doesn't have that information. I think there's an expectation that you know how you're sending to them, and can track that information on your side "pre SendGrid" if desired.

Comment: Hmmm. I think subusers brings me close to the functionality though. If each "subuser" is an app or module. I haven't tried it, but I think it will.

Comment: I came across this for some reason - here's a tip if you want easy way to track this: categories. Your sender can be a category and you can report on that. Look it up.